# Calculate the diameter and radius of a network which has multiple connected components

Tags: python, networkx

My network has several connected components.
I would need to calculate, for each of them, the diameter and radius.

I have tried to loop through each of them, but something is going wrong (error: AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'order')

```
N_comp=[len(c) for c in sorted(nx.connected_components(G), key=len, reverse=True)] # this should return the maximum number of connected components in the network
for i in range(N_comp):

# Calculate average diameter and average path length of connected components
print('Average diameter:{}'.format(nx.diameter(nx.connected_components(G), key=len))))
print('average path length: {}'.format(nx.average_shortest_path_length(nx.connected_components(G), key=len)))
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components), `connected_components` returns "A generator of sets of nodes, one for each component of G."

But these are not subgraphs.  You'll need to take the induced subgraph of `G` on each of these sets of nodes.

From the documentation: "to create the induced subgraph of each component use:  `S = [G.subgraph(c).copy() for c in nx.connected_components(G)]`"

Once you've got `S`, you can do the calculations you want on the elements of `S` (which is something similar to what I think you were trying to create in the list `N_comp`)

In your code there are additional issues.  It looks to me like you've set up a for loop over `N_comp` (which is a list of sets of nodes).  But you never use the things you're looping over, and I don't see any attempt to calculate the diameter of the individual components and then average them.